# Circumvent the Deep Sleep on Samsung?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-contentprovider, samsung

Is there any way you can get around Samsung's Deep Sleep?
For example, we have multiple apps that need to communicate with each other, we are worried that on Samsung devices when they are put into Deep Sleep, it will be impossible to trigger them to do any necessary updates and interactions with each other.

It is quite crucial to our use case that the apps can talk with each other every so often, but from what I know about Deep Sleep, it literally stops all interactions with apps.
I am currently investigating if Account Manager can be used to some how trigger them but I can't find much information on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can necessarily "get around" Deep Sleep, but you can ask the user to set the app to "Never sleep." I found something about it here: https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S20/Stopping-Apps-from-Deep-Sleep/td-p/2566368

Comment: Thanks, I would be curious if it is possible to show a notification to the user and allow this to be done through the app instead of relying on the user to go into the apps settings